# QgsVectorDataProvider capabilities not available in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to use `deleteAttributes` on my vector layer to delete attributes, but it does not work the attributes are not deleted.

`layer.dataProvider().capabilitiesString()` gives the following output:

```
u'Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Simplify Geometries,
Simplify Geometries with topological validation'
```

which confirm `deleteAttribute` is not available. What are the reasons why the function (and the others) are not supported? I am using `QgsVectorDataProvider`.

The layer is created by joining an attribute table (table) (imported from a CSV) to a vector layer (`"layer1"`) using

```
res= processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributestable", layer1, table, "ID", "ID", None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(res['OUTPUT_LAYER'],"join_layer","ogr")
```

`"layer1"` has all capabilities in `QgsVectordataProvider`

```
u'Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes,
Delete Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID,
Change Geometries, Simplify Geometries, Simplify Geometries with topological validation'
```

Comment: layer1 only contains features. the attributes are from the table

Comment: What format are you saving to? Looks like it's a data format which isn't editable -- try shapefiles or geopackage instead.

Comment: it seems that i need to write the layer to a shapefile , remove the layer from the map, then reload the file to the map. Only then I can delete attributes from that layer. But the problem I face now, is I need to write the new layer (with less attributes) as another shapefile, as I could not overwrite the previous one